# LogStash catch my logs only with debug mod

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logstash

I have a little problem on logstash. When I test in debug mode everything is OK with the command

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --debug --path.settings /etc/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/apache.conf
```

But if I start logstash in service with systemctl (systemctl start logstash), it starts but does not trap any log. Nothing happens (the logstash logs do not move ...). All commands in sudo or root.

Logstash and Apach are not on the same machine as Elasticsearch (but it works since in debug they communicate)

Do you know why ?

**EDIT**

This is the pipeline configuration

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/var/log/httpd/access_log"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
    }

    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }

    mutate {
        convert => {
            "response" => "integer"
            "bytes" => "integer"
        }
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
         hosts => "192.168.1.2:9200"
         index => "apache-int-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

And extraction of logstash log id available here : https://sharetext.me/U9RAMT

Comment: Small supplement: I put logstash in debug mode and I notice in both types of execution that my apache configuration file is detected and used.

Comment: You need to provide more information, update your question with your logstash pipeline and logstash logs after you start it using systemd.

Comment: Sure, it's done, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found ... When I started debug mode, I was root, when systemctl starts logstash, it uses user logstash which does not have access to httpd logs!

With the right rights, it works better!